# python subprocess popen issue

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to work with subprocess popen but I am unable to get the command to work. I am trying to run airodump-ng and the normal command is "airodump-ng -c 1 --bssid 00:00:00:00:00:00 -w filename wlan0" and this works. For some reason when being sent from subprocess it tells me the interface is not selected. Also I am having an issue where the output is not changing but it is still printing the same information over and over. Can someone help me here?

```
    import subprocess
    import os 
    
    def start_airodump(channel, bssid, name, interface):
        process = subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng", "-c", channel, "--bssid", bssid, "-w", name, interface], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        buffer = True
        while buffer:
            stdoutput, stderror = process.communicate(timeout=30)
            if len(stdoutput) == 0:
                buffer = False
            if stdoutput:
                print(stdoutput)
            if stderror:
                print("error : " + stderror)
    
    
    start_airodump("1", "00:00:00:00:00:00", "Demo", "wlan0")




      Airodump-ng 1.6  - (C) 2006-2020 Thomas d'Otreppe
  https://www.aircrack-ng.org

  usage: airodump-ng <options> <interface>[,<interface>,...]

  Options:
      --ivs                 : Save only captured IVs
      --gpsd                : Use GPSd
      --write      <prefix> : Dump file prefix
      -w                    : same as --write 
      --beacons             : Record all beacons in dump file
      --update       <secs> : Display update delay in seconds
      --showack             : Prints ack/cts/rts statistics
      -h                    : Hides known stations for --showack
      -f            <msecs> : Time in ms between hopping channels
      --berlin       <secs> : Time before removing the AP/client
                              from the screen when no more packets
                              are received (Default: 120 seconds)
      -r             <file> : Read packets from that file
      -T                    : While reading packets from a file,
                              simulate the arrival rate of them
                              as if they were "live".
      -x            <msecs> : Active Scanning Simulation
      --manufacturer        : Display manufacturer from IEEE OUI list
      --uptime              : Display AP Uptime from Beacon Timestamp
      --wps                 : Display WPS information (if any)
      --output-format
                  <formats> : Output format. Possible values:
                              pcap, ivs, csv, gps, kismet, netxml, logcsv
      --ignore-negative-one : Removes the message that says
                              fixed channel <interface>: -1
      --write-interval
                  <seconds> : Output file(s) write interval in seconds
      --background <enable> : Override background detection.
      -n              <int> : Minimum AP packets recv'd before
                              for displaying it

  Filter options:
      --encrypt   <suite>   : Filter APs by cipher suite
      --netmask <netmask>   : Filter APs by mask
      --bssid     <bssid>   : Filter APs by BSSID
      --essid     <essid>   : Filter APs by ESSID
      --essid-regex <regex> : Filter APs by ESSID using a regular
                              expression
      -a                    : Filter unassociated clients

  By default, airodump-ng hops on 2.4GHz channels.
  You can make it capture on other/specific channel(s) by using:
      --ht20                : Set channel to HT20 (802.11n)
      --ht40-               : Set channel to HT40- (802.11n)
      --ht40+               : Set channel to HT40+ (802.11n)
      --channel <channels>  : Capture on specific channels
      --band <abg>          : Band on which airodump-ng should hop
      -C    <frequencies>   : Uses these frequencies in MHz to hop
      --cswitch  <method>   : Set channel switching method
                    0       : FIFO (default)
                    1       : Round Robin
                    2       : Hop on last
      -s                    : same as --cswitch

      --help                : Displays this usage screen

No interface specified.
```

Comment: There's no `-c` option in the help message. It should be `--channel`

Comment: The -c works in the command line but I still tried it and I have the exact same result of the interface not being specified.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` when you put the arguments in a list.

Comment: You are passing "00:00:00:00:00:00" as the channel, and "1" as the bssid.

Comment: @jasonharper that was a good catch but the command is still not working. I am still getting the "No interface specified" error.

Comment: @Barmar if I run subprocess.popen with shell=False I get a subprocess.TimeoutExpired and it never actually runs.

Comment: How do you decide the command doesn't start running? Does it normally complete before the 30 seconds are out? Have you tried starting another, simpler command to examine what the problem is?

Comment: @Grismar I run a ps aux | grep -i airmon-ng and it returns nothing except the grep command that was running. Plus the 30 second time out doesn't matter if I can't get the command to run correctly.

Comment: There's no mention of `grep` in your example code?

Comment: @grismar because I am not running grep in the code. I am running it in the terminal. I think we are missing the point. The wifi interface wlan0 is not showing up when running the airmon-ng command.